# Can't redirect to the different pages

Tags: php, html

I created a different file for the header(header.html) and I include that file in other pages as well. Now the problem is when I create links for the nav elements ,i cannot redirect to the different pages. I'm running my application in localhost.Can you please tell me what's wrong with that?

Comment: Show us your code. Don't expect help for doing absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This seems wrong.

```
header(header.html);
```

use

```
header("Location: header.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't echo anything before you send the headers. Also check your error logs, it would give you (and us) much more valuable information on whats going wrong here. Headers need to be the first thing sent to the DOM, or in other words NO HTML BEFORE HEADERS!

Comment: I created a different html file for the header.                                                                Code is here   <div id="header">
 <div>
 <a class="lg" href="#">Front of the Theme</a>
 </div>
 <div>
 <a class="hd-btn" >Get Now</a>
 </div>
 <nav >
     <ul class=" ">
      <li class=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="header.html">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 </div>